# Applying discrete uniform law where the sample space is the conditioning event

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Consider the sample space $\{H_1H_2, H_1T_2, T_1H_2, T_1T_2\}$.

Let $C$ be the event $\{H_1H_2, T_1T_2\}.$

Can I apply the Discrete Uniform Law where the sample space is the conditioning event like I did below?

$\mathbb P(C|H_1) = \frac {|C \cap \text {the set of outcomes that contain }H_1|}{|\text {the set of outcomes that contain }H_1|} = \frac {|\{H_1H_2\}|}{|\{H_1H_2, H_1T_1\}|} = \frac12$

$\mathbb P(H_2|H_1) = \frac {|\text {the set of outcomes that contain }H_2| \cap |\text {the set of outcomes that contain }H_1|}{|\{\text {the set of outcomes that contain }H_1\}|} = \frac {|\{H_1H_2\}|}{|\{H_1H_2, H_1T_1\}|} = \frac12$

Comment: In plain English, you seem to be asking for the probability of getting either two Heads or two Tails if I toss a fair coin twice. If so, the answer 1/2 is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, *when but only when*, all of the outcomes in the sample space do have *equal* probability mass, then the probabilities of an event is directly proportional to the count of outcomes of the event.

Take any *non-empty* events $E,C$ that are subsets of such a sample space, $\Omega$, then:

$$\mathsf P(C) = \dfrac{\lvert C\rvert}{\lvert \Omega\rvert}~,~ \mathsf P(E\cap C) =\dfrac{\lvert E\cap C\rvert}{\lvert \Omega\rvert}$$

Therefore, by the definition of conditional probability:

$$\mathsf P(E\mid C) = \dfrac{\lvert E\cap C\rvert}{\lvert C\rvert}$$

That is all.